# In pine-script how to set highs and lows based on conditions?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to code some kind of Darvas box that plots highest highs and lowest lows until there's a breakout.

the usual implementation has a lookback period so the plot changes arbitrarily after a number of bars without respecting any logic.  what I'd like to do is: if the current close goes below the current box low, the box high should also update and change to the current or most recent high,

and viceversa if there is a breach of the current highest high box, the low should move up to the most recent higher low.  essentially start drawing another box boundary  for highs and lows everytime there's a breach, showing better support and resistance for the section.

the commented lines kinda tweak the behaviour like I'm thinking but it feels like a hack and there must be a way to do it better? also at times I see the condition being true but the plot not updating as it should.

````
study("DARVAS BOX",overlay=true, shorttitle="DARVAS")

boxp=input(20, "BOX LENGTH")

LL = lowest(low,boxp)
HH=highest(high,boxp)

NH =    valuewhen(high>HH[1],high,0) 

NL = valuewhen(low<LL[1],low,0) 

//NH :=  LL[1]==LL and LL[2]>LL[1] ? high : NH[1]  
//NH := high>NH? high:NH
//NL :=  HH[1]==HH and HH[2]<HH[1] ? low : NL[1]  
//NL :=  low<NL? low:NL


TopBox = NH// valuewhen(barssince(high>k1[1])  , NH, 1)
BottomBox = NL// valuewhen(barssince(low<LL[1]) , low, 1)

plot(TopBox, linewidth=3, color=green, title="TBbox")
plot(BottomBox, linewidth=3, color=red, title="BBbox")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Script for IQ Options:

```
instrument {
    name = 'Suporte/Resistncia',
    icon = "https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/big-hipermercado-logo.png",
    overlay = True
}

boxp=input (5, "front.newind.darvasbox.length", input.integer, 5)

input_group {
    "Suporte e Resistncia",
    top_color = input { default = "red", type = input.color },
    bottom_color = input { default = "green", type = input.color },
}

RST = boxp

RSTT = value_when(high >= highest(high, RST), high, 0)
RSTB = value_when(low <= lowest(low, RST), low, 0)
plot (RSTT, "Resistance", iff(RSTT ~= RSTT[1], na ,top_color), 4, 0, style.levels, na_mode.restart)
plot (RSTB, "support", iff(RSTB ~= RSTB[1], na ,bottom_color), 4, 0, style.levels, na_mode.restart)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).